# Downloading specific tweets based on country using Flume

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, flume

I want to download specific tweets from Twitter source to HDFS using Flume, e.g. `tweets.country = US`. How can customize Flume for that?

Answer (score 0):

Check this github project for analyzing real time tweets in hadoop using Streaming API.

https://github.com/cloudera/cdh-twitter-example

Make following changes in this program: https://github.com/cloudera/cdh-twitter-example/blob/master/flume-sources/src/main/java/com/cloudera/flume/source/TwitterSource.java

```
double[][] locations = { { 40.714623d, -74.006605d },
            { 42.3583d, -71.0603d } };
FilterQuery query = new FilterQuery().locations(locations);
  twitterStream.filter(query);
```

(line no: 149)